# UICollectionViewCell doesn't fit on screen

Tags: uicollectionview, swift4.2

Does anyone know why this would happen or how to fix it? I am trying to make a simple collection view but for some reason, the cells have a little bit of an offset on the x-axis.
It's supposed to look like this

[image: Text]

But it comes out like this

[image: Text]

Here's what I have

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView:UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
    return CGSize(width: screenWidth, height:135.0)
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay well to solve the issue I just created a brand new view controller in the Storyboard, It was a pain but I honestly could not figure out what was wrong. I think that there must have just been a glitch somewhere in the constraints maybe, but even after I deleted all the constraints I still had the problem. Maybe I'm just the big dumb.